# Footnote conflicts with mathalfa

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, mathalfa

This is my minimal working example (in PDFLaTeX):

`\documentclass[12pt]{article} \usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, geometry, setspace} \usepackage[frak=esstix]{mathalfa} \usepackage{hyperref} \title{Title} \author{Author} \date{\today} \setstretch{1.2} \begin{document} \maketitle $\mathfrak{G}$\footnote{This is footnote}.$\mathfrak{G}$ \end{document}`

The first `\mathfrak{G}` looks good but the second does not. It appears that any `\mathfrak` after `\footnote` cannot be processed properly. If we remove the `mathalfa` package, then no error will occur. But that is not what I want. I tried a lot but all attempts failed to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to load `mathalfa` before `amsmath`.

Comment: @hair-splitter Thanks for your comment. But it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to load the `mathalfa` before `amsmath`. The following code works perfectly for me:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[frak=esstix]{mathalfa} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, geometry, setspace} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\title{Title} 
\author{Author} 
\date{\today} 
\setstretch{1.2} 
\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
$\mathfrak{G}$\footnote{This is footnote}.$\mathfrak{G}$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This really works! The reason why I said it didn’t work is that I put amsmath behind mathalfa instead of putting mathalfa ahead of the five packages…